# stepwise regression using caret in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I have used leaps package in R to perform forward and backward feature elimination. However, I want automate the cross validation and prediction operations. Therefore, how can I use forward/backward selection in caret?

in leaps package you could do it this way

```
forward <- regsubsets(x ~ ., data, nvmax = 20, 
                         method = "forward")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to run a stepwise regression in `caret::train()` with `method=glmStepAIC` from the `MASS` package. For details, see the list of models supported by caret on the [caret documentation website](https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html).

The caret test cases for this model are accessible on the [caret GitHub repository](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/glmStepAIC.R).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @len