# R: error when doing backward feature selection with rms::fastbw on caret model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret

I want to perform backward feature selection using the function `fastbw` from the `rms` package. I use a sample dataset `PimaIndiansDiabetes` as below:

```
library(mlbench)
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

library(caret)
trControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                          repeats = 3,
                          classProbs = TRUE,
                          number = 10, 
                          savePredictions = TRUE,
                          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

caret_model <- train(diabetes~., 
                     data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, 
                     method="glm", 
                     trControl=trControl)

library(rms)
reduced_model <- fastbw(caret_model$finalModel)
```

This gives me an error:

> Error in fastbw(caret_model$finalModel) :    fit does not have design
>   information

May I know what this means and how to resolve it?

Comment: Not sure how to resolve it but `fastbw` requires 'Design' information in model which is `NULL` in your case, `caret_model$finalModel$Design` . See the code here : https://github.com/harrelfe/rms/blob/master/R/fastbw.s#L30

Answer (score 2):

You're probably stuck. `fastbw()` works only with models from `rms`, i.e. `?fastbw` says:

> fit: fit object with ‘Varcov(fit)’ defined (e.g., from ‘ols’,
>             ‘lrm’, ‘cph’, ‘psm’, ‘glmD’)

I tried your fit with `method="lrm"` (`lrm` is `rms`'s logistic regression tool), but got

> Error: Model lrm is not in caret's built-in library

I think you're going to have to find another way to do stepwise regression, e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855807/stepwise-regression-using-caret-in-r): i.e. using `library(MASS)` and then `method="glmStepAIC"` (within  `caret`), or `stepAIC` (from scratch).

It's not obvious to me why you're training a model and *then* doing stepwise regression ...

Comment: If I create a model using `model <- lrm(...)` and then `fastbw(model)`. Then that would give a final trimmed model. I'd like to do the same thing using `caret` because I want to take advantage of its `trainControl` to do K-fold cross validation when training.